# Creation of one of many instances of abstract class

Tags: oop, design-patterns, factory

Since a few days, I am working on a OOP project, where I am trying to adopt best practices and design patterns. I have this problem and I would like to solve it in a elegant way.

I have an abstract object name Node, and a large number of others classes that extends this Node: NodeA, NodeB, ... and NodeZ. 
Every one of this Nodes, had his own creating parameters; for instance, NodeA takes 4 string parameters, NodeB 2 int, NodeC takes a List< Double> and one an object Dog and so on.

I taught of using a Factory< Node>, but this large difference between one Node and the other in the constructors gives me some problems.

What do you think is a good strategy here ? ( I would like to avoid Reflection if possible )

Thanks in advance for any help !

Modified to specify better my problem:
  I have a Tree< Node> and one application that adds nodes to the Tree.
  The creation of these nodes is my problem.

```
Class Application {
  MyTree<Node> tree = new MyTree<Node>();
  void FirstWay()
    {
     NodeA node1 = new NodeA("1","2","3","4");   
     NodeB node2 = new NodeB(10,20); 
     root = tree.takeRoot();
     node1.setChild(node2);
     root.setChild(node1);
    }

  void SecondWay()
    {
        NodeA node1= MyFactory.getNode("NodeA","1","2","3","4");
        NodeB node2= MyFactory.getNode("NodeB",10,20);
        root = tree.takeRoot();
        node1.setChild(node2);
        root.setChild(node1);
    }

}
```

Actually I am trying to understand who should be in charge of creating one object. Could you give me some guidelines ?
Thanks!!!

**Edited** :

I am building a 3D engine and I have a set of nodes that will go inside the SceneTree. Each of this nodes has peculiar properties specific of the node. The Node_Camera will have objects and parameters to setup the camera. The Node_Material will contain material properties and the Node_Geometry will have geometry stuff.

I think I will go for a Factory model. This way when in the future I will implement xml parsing of a scene, I will have ready functionalities to use when reading the xml.

Comment: "Who should be in charge of creating one object" : what object ? How could we know ? You should provide more details about your application and the intended use of trees and nodes...

Comment: Why can't your factory produce many kinds of nodes? `.createNodeA()`, `.createNodeB()`, etc? This makes sense if you need to pass a factory around or keep some coordinated state that affects creation of all types of nodes. (Also consider fluid interface: `tree.getRoot().append(node1).append(node2)`)

Comment: Also, why use a Factory in the first place ? What problem does it solve for you ?

Comment: To 9000: I would prefer to have a single entry point for creating objects.
To guillaume31: Creating every object, a guideline, if any, that could help me to understand in every project who should be in charge of create one object.
The factory could create the object and the same time start other accessorial functionalities on the node, like notify subscribers of nodes type A that one of them is now around.
I would like to understand

Comment: I feel like your problem is somewhere else. Why do you have so many Node? What are the use for each of the parameters in the constructor?

Comment: May be provide the full example , because it would help us in understanding your scenario better and provide some other solution if that makes sense . Currently what i could ask myself is , why there is no relation at all between different nodes , if there is no relation how can these be handled at your base class ? So please provide full example with your requirements.

Comment: They appear to be DTO's so there's really no need to do anything special - go with the first example and `new` them up as and when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are valid. As you say in your comment, the factory is useful if there is other activities associated with the creation of a node, e.g., notification.  I suggest not over-thinking at the start of a project.  Spend a little time to pick what seems like a good approach, and be prepared to change if you run into problems.  "Listen to the code", it will tell you when to change.

Comment: While we should all be aware of design patterns and 'best practices' to avoid reinventing the wheel, beware of using these everywhere just because they exist.  Do the simplest thing that works for your situation.